# Domain Driven Desgin - Problems with a real example

Tags: domain-driven-design

I want to dive into "DDD" and am facing some issues in how to explicitly implement one case the "DDD"-way. Here is a part of my domain model.
[image: domain model]

What I want to achive is the following: Let's say I have a technician driving to some customers. He divides his visits in multiple tour's on a day. So for example on one day he has a tour in the morning with 3 visits, and one in the afternoon with 2 visits. At each visit he takes some activities, one or more, which also can have subactivities.

The technician get's payed by a payment agreement which has position for each activity. The agreement may change over time so it has some dates to determine when it is active. To map the activity to an activity position, it has an abstract ID which will be translated to an contrete ActivitiPosition based on the PaymentAgreement.

Now the technician wants to book a day and create an Invoice or add InvoicePositions to an existing one. To create an InvoicePosition I need information from the Tour (driven kilometers), the visit (the paymentagreement may vary based on the customer), the activities and the PaymentAgreement which is valid at that day.

There is some validation needed before booking a day and there are a some special cases in the business logic which I will not elaborate further.

My question now is: Who is responsible for creating what in the "DDD"-way? Should I create a factory method in InvoicePosition which takes the km, the visit, the activity and a source of PaymentAgreement (to determine the actual one, as holding access to a repository should not be done in the entities, right?)? Or should I hand over all information to the Activity to create an InvoicePosition (or a list of InvoicePositions)? Or should there be an extra object (some kind of converter?)?

Is handing over a "source" (which would be a repository) of PaymentAgreements to the converting function a good choice? Is there an alternative solution?

And one extra question to Java/CDI developers: As the entities are not in a CDI context, what is an accurate way of firing CDI events as domain events? This is a JavaEE project. Should every entity be managed by CDI? Or do I have to manually inject a CDI eventbus into every entity (I do not hope so, as this somehow seems to be a drity hack than a clean solution to me)?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably take two different approaches.  You'll have a bunch of inputs from the real world, representations of what happened outside of the model's control that you cache and preserve.  This part is mostly just data collection, you don't have a rich domain model here because there are no invariants to protect.

Then in addition to that, you'll have a domain model that, given these collected samples as inputs, calculates your invoice positions.  This is your rich model, and its positions will be based on what inputs it has received.  So there's a certain amount of orchestration to be done (Bob reported this information from this job, we write it down, and now we pass that information along to the domain model to be incorporated into the positions).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the question is that it is misses the context and service boundaries, but that is key to determine the right strategy.

Are these aggregates live within the same context and service boundary? If so it may be perfectly fine to just implement the desired operations in any traditional ways, for example as a monolith.

If they live in different services or contexts, one of those services will need to be able to access all information required for the desired operation. This can be done in a few ways, but the two typical approaches I see are:

- Let one of the services, which owns the aggregate to be updated query other services for the required information. The problem with this is that it reduces availability (any of the dependent services are down can cause the operation to fail), and has performance penalties.
- The more robust albeit less "normalized" approach is to let the service owning the aggregate to be updated duplicate any additional required information from the other services as a local replica, and use that as the source for the information for the operation. In an Event Driven case it can be done by subscribing the services to each other's events to keep their local replicas updated.

Finally, if the operation requires updates to be made to multiple aggregates not owned by a single service, you need to implement a Saga, which is in simple terms a method to control multiple services in order to perform parts of the main operation. The additional challenges of this are the more complex transaction and error handling. The two most common approaches to implement Sagas are Orchestration and Choreography. These are models to control the involved services in a specific way to achieve an end goal. In a Choreography setup each service reacts to the events of other services without a central controller. Orchestration on he other hand is when there is a dedicated service that controls all others in order to achieve the goal of the Saga.

Please note these are layman termed explanations. My purpose is to give pointers, but these concepts each can be elaborated on for hundreds of pages, so do your research indeed!